# Total charge calculation of a spherically symmetric electric potential in the background of a Schwarzschild like metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, black-holes, charge, potential

Given a static, spherically symmetric electric potential $\phi(r)$ in a d-dimensional spacetime with a background metric of a d-dimensional Schwarzschild-Tangherlini black hole, i.e.:
$$ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+\frac{1}{f(r)}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2_{d-2}$$
Where:
$$f(r)=1-\left(\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{d-3}$$
$r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius and $d\Omega^2_{d-2}$ is the metric on the unit $S^{d-2}$ sphere.

From the classical theory of electromagnetism the total charge $Q$ is given by the following spatial integral over all the space $V$ in spherical coordinates:

$$Q=-\int_V d^{d-1}rJ(r,\varphi_1,...,\varphi_{d-2})\nabla^2\phi(r)$$
Where $J(r,\varphi_1,...,\varphi_{d-2})$ is the jacobian given for example for the case of $d-1=3$ spatial dimensions as:
$$J(r,\varphi,\theta)=r^2\sin(\theta)$$

In curved spacetime integrals over d-dimensional objects are calculated as follow:
$$I=-\int_V d^{d}r \sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi(r)$$
Where the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\mu}$ is acting on vector field for example $\partial_{\nu}\phi(r)$ as follows:

$$ \nabla_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} \phi(r) = \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} \phi(r) - \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha} \partial_{\alpha} \phi(r) $$
With $\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha}$ a Christophel symbol and $g=\det{g_{\mu\nu}}$.

How to calculate the total charge in the Schwarzschild-Tangherlini black hole background?

We begin by integrating out the spherical part, and we left with:
$$Q=-\Omega_{d-2}\int_{0}^{\infty} dr \sqrt{-\tilde{g}}r^{d-2}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi(r)$$
Where $\Omega_{d-2}$ is the surface area of a $d-2$ unit sphere.

But what is $\tilde{g}$? is this $\tilde{g}=g_{tt}g_{rr}=-1$? $\tilde{g}=g_{rr}=\frac{1}{f(r)}$? or something else?

Comment: Don’t you want to turn the volume integral into a surface integral so you can compute the flux? Maybe over a surface infinitely far away?

Comment: @Ghoster Ok. given what you said, we calculate ${E}_\nu(r)=-\partial_{\nu}\phi(r)$ and now:

$$-\int_{V}d^{d-1}r\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu} E_{\nu}=-\int_{S}d^{d-2}r\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}E_{\nu}n_{\mu}$$ where $n_{\mu}$ is the normal vector to the sphere at infinity. doing the integration will yield:
$$Q = -\Omega_{d-2}r_{\infty}^{d-2}\sqrt{-\tilde{g}}g^{rr} E_{r}(r_\infty)$$ where $r_{\infty}=\infty$ ,but what is $\tilde{g}$?